# Need specific Tags in existing CSV against the specified values using powershell

Tags: powershell

Input [Original CSV][1]   output: [Required Output][2]I have a .csv file in which columns with header "System Name", "Domain Name", **"AMCore content version"**,"IP Address", "Managed State", etc.

The system name column contains each unique names & the column "AMCore content version" will have some numeric values, for ex. 4111, 4110, 4109, 4108 ... 3111 etc. Need to add a new column "Compliance Status" using powershell in the file, suppose if today's AMCore version is 4111 then it is N & i need to mark n-3 as "Compliant" in the new column for the n to n-3 (4111, 4110, 4109, 4108) & all lower then n-4 will be tagged as "Non-compliant". Also if the value in the "AMCore content version" is blank then check "Managed state" where if the value is "unmanaged" then tag it as "unmanaged" in "Compliance Status", if the value in Amcore version is 0 & is Managed in managed state then mark as "Check ENS".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [1] so ... what have you tried? what failed to work as needed? ///// [2] please add a sanitized version of the 1st few lines of your CSV and what result you want from those lines.

Comment: Thanks for response, I am new to powershell & I was trying to take help from internet but failed. I have added the original CSV image & the required output image. Need a script where I will define current/today's "AMCore content version" value & it will automatically tag n to n-4 as "Compliant" in "Compliance Status" column & rest will be tagged as "non-compliant", if the value is blank, then it will check managed column & if the system is unmanaged then it will mark it as unmanaged in "compliance state"

Thanks :)

Comment: you are most welcome! [*grin*] ///// however, posting _images_ of code/errors/data is not proper here. **_please replace the images with text._** why? lookee ... Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question